# Android Studio - Kotlin Project's "Unsolved reference" problem

Tags: android, kotlin

I add a textView in layout but when I'm trying to use Kotlin Android Extensions but I get **Unsolved reference** error on my TextView:

```
        package com.normal.ff

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}

fun first(a:Int, b:Int){
    textView.text

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*` at the top of your activity.

Comment: Noops its say 'Unused import directive'

Comment: It is because you add import manually. On setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) click Ali+Enter and add import. Of course if when you manually add import and it doesn't work, try File->Invalidate caches/restart

Comment: it just worked on the 'onCreate' function, when i create a new function i get the same error.

Comment: File->Invalidate caches/Restart @Sezer

Comment: Thanks but it's just worked on 'onCreate' fun not other functions... [https://imgbu.com/i/Mxn06 ]

Comment: OK, why your function is out of class?! Put it into MainActivity class. @Sezer

Comment: If your problem is solved, check correct answer @Sezer

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, you just need a reference from layout file for that text view.

something like below

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var textView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
    }
}

fun first (a:Int, b:Int){
    val text = textView.text
}
```